# Socket.emit() outside socket.on()

Tags: socket.io

Do we always have to use socket.emit() inside a socket.on() like that:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('User connected !');
    retrieveDictionnary((dictionnary) =>{
     socket.emit('dictionnarySend', dictionnary);
    }
}
```

I want to create on my client side a function which ask information to the server when I click on a button:

```
translateServer(parameter, control){
        this.socket.emit('translate', [parameter,control]);
}
```

But it seems that it's not working, the server never receive this message.

Thank you !

Comment: This question is incomplete.  You need to show a lot more client-side code so we can see how you make a socket.io connection to the server, how you store the `socket` variable, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pattern you are using above is the recommended way of interacting with a socket (ie acquiring a `socket` instance when the 'connection' event fires, and then calling `emit()` from that socket instance, etc).

If I understand your client-side requirements correctly, you are wanting to send data to the server via web sockets - are you sure the socket that you have established a web socket connection between the client and server?

For instance, if you add the following to your client-side code, you should see a success message in your console:

```
const socket = io.connect('YOUR SERVER ADDRESS');

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected to server!');

  // [UPDATE]
  // This assumes you have a <button> element on your page. When
  // clicked, a message will be sent to the server via sockets
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', (event) => { 

      // Prevent button click reloading page
      event.preventDefault();

      // Send message to server via socket
      socket.emit('MESSAGE_ID', 'test message from client' + new Date());
  });

});
```

## Update

This shows your original server code, expanded with the detail needed to receive and print data sent from client via sockets:

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('User connected !');

    // Register a server handler for any messages from client on MESSAGE_ID channel
    socket.on('MESSAGE_ID', (message) => {

      // Print the message received from client in console  
      console.log('message from client', message);
    })

    retrieveDictionnary((dictionnary) =>{
         socket.emit('dictionnarySend', dictionnary);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is, I have some `socket.on()` working on my client side. I can receive on the client the information from the socket `dictionnarySend` sent by the server.

Comment: I've succeed in sending data from the server to the client but not in the other side